# depending dropdown based on cell value and named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel files

- file one has multiple sheets
  Each sheet holds a table with a defined name which looks like "table_1" - "table_2" - etc.
  the first column of these tables holds codes/numbers
- file two has a table in which I want to add a validation to the second column, named "Code"
  Based on the value (1 -2 - 3,...) in the first column, named "Cluster", the second column should have a dropdown populated with the values of the first column of table_1 - table_2...

to achieve this, I defined a name in file two which refers to the first column of the table in file one
code_1 refers to table_1(Code)...

now I set

```
Dim s_formule As String
s_formule = "=code_" & table_tab.ListColumns("Cluster").DataBodyRange.Value

table_tab.ListColumns("Code").DataBodyRange.Validation.Add _
    Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=s_formule
```

This works, but the problem is I have to rerun the macro to load the the string into the formula1
I tried to put the string directly to the Formula1, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: yes the code should run after each change in the cell in the first column

Comment: I get it working, just put in the relative cell ref in the macro
`Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""code_""&A15)"`

Excel will automatically change that in the new table row